# Feign Client : use jar running (CompletableFuture.supplyAsync call Feign Client throw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, feign

when i up jdk version 8 -> 17, spring cloud version 2020.0.3, spring boot 2.5.4;

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync call Feign Client Code working abnormally；

```
@FeignClient(value = "mall-product", configuration = {FeignErrorDecoder.class, FeignInterceptor.class, FeignConfig.class}, decode404 = true, contextId = "mall-product-productSku")
public interface ProductSkuFeignClient {
    default List<ProductSimpleResponse> findSimpleInfoByProductIds(List<Integer> productIds) {
        List<List<Integer>> lists = CompletableFutureUtil.splitList1000(productIds.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        List<List<ProductSimpleResponse>> responses = CompletableFutureUtil.allOfTaskAndReturn(ids ->
                findSimpleInfoByProductIds(new ProductIdsRequest(ids)), lists);
        return responses.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/product/sku/simple/info/by/productIds")
    List<ProductSimpleResponse> findSimpleInfoByProductIds(@RequestBody ProductIdsRequest request);
}
```

```
    public static <T, R> List<R> allOfTaskAndReturn(Function<T, R> function, List<T> objects) {
        List<CompletableFuture<R>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                    function.apply(objects.get(finalI)), pool));
        }
        CompletableFuture<Void> allCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture
                .allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
        return allCompletableFuture.thenApply(e ->
                futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())).join();
    }
```

> 2021-11-03 02:34:53.078 [http-nio-8095-exec-4] [ERROR] [5cc877af-3b0a-450e-af46-469b9c20378c] j.c.f.c.CommonGlobalExceptionHandler@toLog:57 - CompletionException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition]
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1770)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1760)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)

Comment: Did you update Java and Springboot as well?

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>


Is this the dependency you are using?

Comment: please put your pom in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. Please see the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/475) and a workaround that can be applied till the issue is fixed [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/600#issuecomment-916737892).